# Property update to trigger the another method of an object

Tags: javascript

How can I create a constructor so that setting or changing property on its object automatically triggers one  of its own method or other function?

```
function Creator(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.reverse="dont"
    this.reversal=function(){/*code to reverse name */}

}
```

I want to achieve following:

```
 var my_name=new Creator("Chris");
 my_name.reverse="do" // THIS SHOULD AUTOMATICALLY RUN my_name.reversal METHOD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Object.defineProperty() to make a getter-setter that also triggers:

```
function Creator(name){
    this.name=name;
    var isRev="dont";
    Object.defineProperty(this,"reverse", {
         get: function(){return isRev},
         set: function(v){isRev=v; this.reversal(); }
    });
    this.reversal=function(){this.name=this.name.split("").reverse().join("");}
}

fred=new Creator("fred");
r=[fred.name];
fred.reverse="do";
r.push(fred.name);
alert(r);
```

which shows "fred,derf" in the alert

it's coded exactly like yours, which is a little bit weird since the value of "reverse" doesn't seem to matter, but this will get you going with the main challenge of subscribing actions to property changes.

Comment: Thanks Dan.....I had completely forgotten that!!!! I had read it, I mean, week ago on David Flanagan's book. Very thanks to you...